# How can I show Privacy dialog popup to ask visitor to allow flash plugin for browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flash, swfobject

How can I show privacy dialog popup to ask visitor to allow flash plugin for browser using java script or whatever?

So I need the popup like the one in image:

[image: popup-to-enable-flash]

I read that if I used SWFobject then automatically this pop-up will show up if its not enabled, i tried it and did not work for me.
I tried a lot of solutions like get version of Flash plugin then try to trigger the pop-up, and none of solutions i tried worked for me like:

```
if(browserName()=="chrome")
{
PluginDetect.getVersion(".");
var version = PluginDetect.getVersion('Flash');
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution Its just to pul this tag and it will check if flash exists and not enabled it will ask you to enable it, if not exists it will redirect you to downlad page

```
<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer/" class="button">GET FLASH PLAYER</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" class="button">GET FLASH PLAYER</a>
```